# If <select> option.val() is "x", do not .show() div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click my submit button, I only want it to show/hide the divs if the value of the select option is 2-6. If the value is 1 (disabled option) I do not want the button click to do anything.

```
<select id="brand_bu" name="selected" class="form-control" onchange="panelHeader()">
                    <option value="1" disabled selected>Please Select a Option..</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                </select>
<span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" type="button">Refresh Table</button>
                    </span>



$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function(){

    $("#hide").hide();
    $("#show").show();

});
```

});

This is what I have tried to do with a if statement but I cant seem to get it working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function() {

    if($("#brand_bu").val() != "1"){

    $("#hide").hide();
    $("#show").show();
      }
});
```

});

Comment: You have no elements with IDs 'hide' or 'show'

Comment: id of your button element is "submit", not "submitbu". is it a type-o? if not your click function will not work.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I did not include the hide or show elements, they are simple <div id="show"></div> elements

Comment: are you getting any errors? or just nothing happens?

Comment: Nothing happens when I run my if statement.

Comment: i changed nothing from your code. here in this jsfiddle.net/w4o8eb5b/ your code running as its should be. may be your jquery doesn't loading at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/nozhs1v2/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").prop("disabled",true);
    $("#hide").hide();
    $("#show").hide();
});

$("#brand_bu").change(function(){

    if($(this).val() != 1){
        $("#submit").prop("disabled",false);
    }
    else {
     $("#submit").prop("disabled",true);

    }

})

$("#submit").click(function(){
 $("#hide").show();
    $("#show").show();
})
```

I changed your html code and js code. Please look into the jsfiddle too.

Comment: This is half way there. I only want to show/hide divs on button click. With this, as soon as the value changes, the divs show and hide right away before the click. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

- You need those elements
- Your click selector was wrong - that ID didn't exist
- Using `.val()` [doesn't work for disabled elements](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13097), so instead, use `selectedIndex()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    if ($("#brand_bu").prop('selectedIndex') != "0") {
      $("#hide").hide();
      $("#show").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="brand_bu" name="selected" class="form-control" onchange="panelHeader()">
  <option value="1" disabled selected>Please Select a Option..</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" type="button">Refresh Table</button>
                    </span>

<div id='hide'>hide</div>
<div id='show'>show</div>
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I fixed that part. How does the javascript look?

Comment: When I use this, nothing happens when I click.

Comment: @khush123456 please try again - I just edited. If it's not working for you, it's possible jQuery isn't loading for you...